# .htaccess make https://www.mysite.com go to https://mysite.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'd like my htaccess file to make any url gone to with a `www` to be removed...

For example, if I was to go to:

```
https://www.mysite.com
```

I'd need to be redirected to:

```
https://mysite.com
```

---

The site is SSL encrypted, so all URL's should have https://

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```